# Having trouble with array being overwritten

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to load a scrabble dictionary to memory, but when I print out the contents of the dictionary, it seems to have rewritten every string in my data array with the last string seen by the buf, for example, when I print out the data array at the very end, every entry in the array is 'zzz' because its the last entry in scrabble.txt. I don't understand why it is being overwritten? What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 100

struct data_t {
    int nval;       /* current number of values in array */
    int max;        /* allocated number of values */
    char **data;        /* the data array */
};

enum {INIT = 1, GROW = 2};

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("scrabble.txt", "r");
    char buf[LEN];
    int i = 0;
    struct data_t *data = malloc(sizeof(struct data_t));
    data->nval = INIT;
    data->max = INIT;
    data->data = NULL;
    while (fgets(buf, LEN, fp)) {
            if (data->data == NULL) {
                    data->data = malloc(LEN);
                    assert(data->data);
            }
            else if (data->nval > data->max) {
                    data->data = realloc(data->data, GROW * data->max * LEN);
                    assert(data->data);
                    data->max = GROW * data->max;
            }
            //printf("%s\n",buf);
            data->data[i] = buf;
            //printf("data->data[%d] = %s ", i, data->data[i]);
            i++;
            data->nval++;
    }
    /* overcounted */
    data->nval--;

    for(i = 0; i < data->nval; i++)
            printf("data->data[%d] = %s", i, data->data[i]);

    fclose(fp);
    free(data->data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW `data->data = malloc(LEN);`--> `data->data = malloc(sizeof(char*));`, also `data->data = realloc(data->data, GROW * data->max * sizeof(char*));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write:

```
data->data[i] = buf;
```

This makes the pointer `data->data[i]` point at the buffer `buf`.  You do this every time around the loop, so you end up with all of your pointers pointing to `buf`.  So when you output what each pointer is pointing to, it outputs the contents of `buf` that many times.

You probably wanted to use a different buffer for each line. You will have to use `malloc` or related to allocate those buffers. For example, replace `data->data[i] = buf;` with:

```
data->data[i] = strdup(buf);
```

(`strdup` is not a Standard C function, but if your system doesn't have it, you can `malloc(strlen(buf)+1)` followed by `strcpy`).